# auto clicking bot that clicks a changing button

Tags: php, html, bots

there is a game made in php and there are 3 buttons when you open the page 2 buttons turn red and 1 button turns blue. when you click the blue button the buttons change now a different button is blue. is there any way i/someone can make a bot that clicks the blue button every time? here is a small bit of code from the source of the sigh if it helps.

> first button (blue)

```
<td align="center"><input id="Button099811" name="Button099811" 
onmouseup="GameAJAX(&quot;DoAction-20&amp;anti=099811255ed3e2964b19af630&quot;, 
&quot;SkillArea&quot;); $(&quot;.read_more2&quot;).val(&quot;Loading...&quot;); 
$(&quot;.read_more3&quot;).val(&quot;Loading...&quot;);" type="button" value="Mine RuneStone"
class="action_button read_more2" style="width: auto; padding: 15px;"></td>
```

> other 2 (red)

```
<td align="center"><input id="Button928852" name="Button928852" 
onmouseup="GameAJAX(&quot;Skills&quot;, &quot;PageContent&quot;); 
$(&quot;.read_more3&quot;).val(&quot;WRONG!&quot;);" type="button" value="Mine RuneStone" 
class="read_more3 action_button" style="width: auto; padding: 15px;"></td>
```

i am not very good with this type of code but if someone could give/tell me how to make something that would be great

Comment: Do the classes `read_more2` and `read_more3` relate to the button color?

Comment: Is there something that can easily detect if the element is 'blue'? Is there a css class that means it is blue?

Comment: i am not very good with this type of code but if someone could make something that would be great.

Comment: "i am not very good with this type of code but if someone could make something that would be great" translation "Gimme da COdeZ" - Answer... No

Comment: Need to try stuff out first.  The peeps here on SO aren't going to write your solutions for you.  (They will help you troubleshoot though if you are giving a good effort and have an understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.)

Comment: you might be able to use window.getComputedStyle() in Javascript.
http://mzl.la/Sh0UYI  You might have to do some reverse engineering to see which properties determined the blue color such as printing the computed style values to the console and comparing the different buttons.

Comment: ok i just looked in the code a bit more and it looks like read_more2 is only in the blue buttons.

Comment: @xal3xhx Well then the game designers did not try very hard to protect this game from bots, which is good for you I suppose

Comment: @NathanielWendt well he made it so that people who pay money could have a auto click so he might have did that because of that. but... i dont thing that is in the code yet

Comment: @relentless it looks like read_more2 is only in the blue button and read_more3 is in the 2 red buttons.

Comment: ok, so start writing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a chrome extension that scraped the page for input tags with the class `read_more2`.

A great resource for learning how to make your own chrome extension is:
http://css-tricks.com/colorpeek-part-2-building-first-chrome-extension/

Once you have the basics, you will want to create a content-script extension.  To do so, in your manifest.json file include something along the lines of:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["url of the game"],
    "js": ["jquery.js","myscript.js"]
  }
]
```

This will invoke myscript.js when you are visiting a page that matches the url of your game.  Also make sure to include the jquery library.  Then, in your myscript.js page:

```
$("input.read_more2").click();
```

This should give you the basics needed to get you started.  Make sure to always read up as much as possible in order to ask questions that show initiative.

Comment: thank you for the help! i will start reading :).

Comment: No problem, welcome to web development.